Adding alternates to NextJS sitemap causes error
This is my sitemap.ts file which I took from Next documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/sitemap#generate-a-localized-sitemap
import { MetadataRoute } from 'next'

export default function sitemap(): MetadataRoute.Sitemap {
  return [
    {
      url: 'https://acme.com',
      lastModified: new Date(),
      alternates: {
        languages: {
          es: 'https://acme.com',
          en: 'https://acme.com/en',
        },
      },
    }
  ]
}

but when I visit the url/sitemap.xml it returns this:
https://acme.com 2024-06-12T09:41:57.545Z
Is there any way to fix this?
Thank you!
When I remove the "alternates" snippet and keep the rest, the sitemap works as expected.

I'm really not sure why the sitemap is being displayed like that but it seems to be rendered correctly if you inspect the console, so I posted it and checked on Google Search Console and the sitemap is being fetched successfully, so I guess it works nonetheless. You can check the sitemap here: https://matuca.es/sitemap.xml

were you able to fix the issue? I am having the same issue

Hi! I think the problem is in the way the sitemap is displayed. I inspected the sitemap url and I could see that the sitemap is rendering correctly, and it's working in production so I just used it like that :S

Thank you for your response. I also see the sitemap, but it doesn't render the way it shows in the Next.js Docs. Additionally, when indexing the site in Google Search Console, it doesn't see the website in other locales except for the default language.

Hi! :) I've managed to implement a workaround that I found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/161cbms/creating_a_sitemap_with_translated_alternate/
Now my default page and my alternate page are being indexed on Google correctly.

I have been experiencing this same problem on several browsers when visiting /sitemap.xml
Downloading the sitemap.xml page then opening it as a .txt file shows the correct format
According to this post the sitemap is properly generated (and valid if run through a validator), but just poorly displayed
Proof: https://pysubs.vercel.app/sitemap.xml (shows a bad format)
Yet is valid:

